# How to reuse sync code in async method using C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Suppose an interface and consider this following code, it's my contract

```
public interface ISomeContract
{
    Task<int> SomeMethodAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    int SomeMethod();
}
```

now imagine contract's implementation of ISomeContract with following code

```
public class SomeImplementation : ISomeContract
    {
        public int SomeMethod()
        {
            // a lot of code ...
            return 10;
        }

        public async Task<int> SomeMethodAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return SomeMethod();

            // another example: I can remove async modifier from SomeMethodAsync method and this following.

            //try
            //{
            //    return Task.FromResult<int>(SomeMethod());
            //}
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{
            //    return Task.FromException<int>(ex);
            //}
        }
    }
```

As you see, I've no await-able code there,
How can I reuse SomeMethod body in case I've no await-able code really?
even more I tested Task.FromResult without async symbol in method header, but how is it possible to attain best solution for this problem?

Comment: *"How can I reuse SomeMethod body"* you're doing exactly that in the code you posted, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm just looking for best practice of it's problem

Comment: Assuming you *have* to provide an async implementation (eg because other implementations of this interface are really async), you did the right thing here.

Comment: Thanks, but my challenge is only this warning after each build 
`warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls`,
It's not a big deal but I prefer to have clean output ;))

Comment: Ooh now I see, you should have included that into the question! You could either write a wrapper which basically does your "alternate example" thing, or just `return await Task.FromResult(SomeMethod());`

Comment: Just remove async...

Comment: what do you think about this code, I guess it can solve this issue `return await Task.Run(() => SomeMethod());`

Comment: it works without removing async symbol

Comment: Best practice here depends on what exactly you do in SomeMethod. Do you read any files, query database, make http (or other) requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a single perfect answer here: it somewhat depends on what you want to do.

First off, we should decide whether or not consumers of the contract will expect `SomeMethodAsync()` to return quickly because it's an async method. In that case, if `SomeMethod()` is slow we may want to use `Task.Run()` to achieve that even though this is often considered a bad practice:

```
// if you think that "returns quickly" is an important guarantee of SomeMethodAsync
public Task<int> SomeMethodAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(), cancellationToken);
}
```

You can see MSFT taking this approach with the [default implementation of TextReader.ReadAsync](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textreader.cs,3ab5dca4aa74d50e), for example.

If `SomeMethod()` is reasonably fast or we don't care about returning quickly (which technically async methods do not guarantee), then we want some approach that simulates the behavior of an async method that happens to run synchronously. In particular, failures/cancellation should result in a faulted/canceled task. One way to do this is to simply use an async method as you show:

```
public async Task<int> SomeMethodAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    return SomeMethod();
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it's very simple and yet fully correct. Another advantage is that certain primitive task results are cached by the runtime in a way that they are not when using `Task.FromResult`. For example, the zero task is cached:

```
public async Task<int> Z() => 0;

void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Task.FromResult(0) == Task.FromResult(0)); // false
    Console.WriteLine(Z() == Z()); // true
}
```

Thus, you may get some performance benefits if you frequently return these common values.

The main disadvantage of this is that it will generate a build warning because you have an async method with no awaits. You can suppress it with a `#pragma`, but that makes the code ugly and may still confuse other devs reading the code. Another slight disadvantage is that this will likely be marginally less performant than manually constructing tasks in some cases. For example, in the case where the passed-in token is canceled, we have to communicate this by throwing an exception.

That leads us to something like your second option, slightly tweaked to properly handle cancellation:

```
public Task<int> SomeMethodAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return Task.FromCanceled<int>(cancellationToken);
    }

    try { return Task.FromResult(SomeMethod()); }
    catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
    {
        var canceledTaskBuilder = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        canceledTaskBuilder.SetCanceled();
        return canceledTaskBuilder.Task;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Task.FromException<int>(e);
    }
}
```

This is pretty clunky, so most of the time I'd go with one of the first two options or write a helper method to wrap the code from the third option.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add that IF you do any IO in your `SomeMethod`, you don't want to actually reuse it (using `Task.Run` or any other method). Instead, you want to rewrite it using asynchronous IO, because one of the main points of using async at all is to leverage that asynchronous IO. For example, suppose you have this:

```
public long SomeMethod(string url)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    return response.ContentLength;
}
```

In this case, you don't want to reuse this method in your `SomeMethodAsync`, because you do `request.GetResponse()`, which is IO, and it has async version. So you have to do it this way:

```
public async Task<long> SomeMethodAsync(string url, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
    using (cancellationToken.Register(() => request.Abort(), false)) {
        try {
            var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            return response.ContentLength;
        }
        catch (WebException ex) {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                throw new OperationCanceledException(ex.Message, ex, cancellationToken);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it's somewhat longer in this case (because `GetResponseAsync` does not accept cancellation tokens), but it would be correct way in case you use any IO.